# How to stop Ctrl + A moving cursor to beginning of line everywhere?

Tags: shortcut-keys, keyboard

#### Ctrl + A moving cursor to beginning of line Everywhere

I know that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> should move the cursor to the beginning of the line *in terminal,* but problem is **it's doing it everywhere.** Address bar, text editors everywhere.

I have just installed 12.04 and this is really annoying.

Do I have to uninstall anything, because I remember *this problem was not there initially.* I have installed LAMP and a few other applications but I don't think that will be causing this.

Please help...

Comment: Have you installed any tweaking tools such as gnome-tweak? [This answer](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1866963) suggests setting an Emacs keybinding in that would result in the behaviour you're seeing.

Comment: Okay I'll add it as an answer. Please take some time to accept it so future users will be able to see that this problem is soluble quickly and easily. Glad to be of help.

Answer (score 1):

Installing tweaking tools such as gnome-tweak then setting an Emacs keybinding with them would result in the behaviour you're seeing, as in [this answer](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1866963). Disable any Emacs keybindings you have set in tweak tools and that should fix your problem.